# How to Proportionately Adjust Vertical Spacing Between the Lines in a Scaled Minipage Environment

Tags: minipage, scaling, text-manipulation, vertical-spacing

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\lipsum[19] 
\vspace*{20pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{4.00in}
\textbf{\scalefont{0.75}{\color{red}{THIS IS A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT IN WHICH THE FONTSIZE HAS BEEN SCALED DOWN---BUT THE SPACING BETWEEN THE LINES SEEMS TO HAVE BEEN UNAFFECTED}}---I WOULD LIKE TO REDUCE THE VERTICAL SPACE BETWEEN THE LINES PROPORTIONATELY.}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Although the text in the minipage environment appears to have been scaled by a factor of 0.75, the vertical spacing between the lines has not. (To see this more clearly, try scaling by a factor of, say, 0.15).

QUESTION: How may I proportionately adjust the vertical spacing in a scaled minipage environment so that it reflects the scaling imposed on the text?

Thank you.

Comment: Use `\scalebox{0.75}{\begin{minipage}{4.00in}`... Not `\scalefnt`

Comment: as I commented previously there is no reason to use `\scalefont` here (or anywhere) you could just select thesize you want rather than the wrong size then scaling. but (again) you have closed the scope before ending the paragraph so you get the wrong baseline. `\scalefont` _does_ scale the baseline and font size by the same amount.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always the line spacing used in a paragraph is the one in force at the end of the paragraph, so if you want the baseline spacing that is set by `\scalefont` you need (just as if you had used `\small`) to end the paragraph within its scope.

[image]

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\lipsum[19] 
\vspace*{20pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{4.00in}
\bfseries\scalefont{0.75}{\color{red}THIS IS A MINIPAGE ENVIRONMENT IN WHICH THE FONTSIZE HAS BEEN SCALED DOWN---BUT THE SPACING BETWEEN THE LINES SEEMS TO HAVE BEEN UNAFFECTED}---I WOULD LIKE TO REDUCE THE VERTICAL SPACE BETWEEN THE LINES PROPORTIONATELY.
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you know when to use `scalefnt` such as you have used here, and when, say, to use `scalebox` as has been noted in a previous comment, that would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @mlchristians well they are not that related, scalefnt is a font size command so just selects a smaller font. scalebox uses back end extensions to scale a region of the output so would scale anything (the width of the minpipage for example) and any rules or images, plus of course it is a box so unbreakable whereas scalefnt is just a font change. (still can't see why you don't just use `\large` as you seem to be selecting a 12pt font more or less, by scaling down  `\LARGE`.

Comment: @mlchristians apparently I wrote `\scalefnt` in 1997 but I doubt that I have ever used it since.

Comment: @mlchristians note that `\scalefont` scales the _requested size_ not the font so here you are asking for a 12pt font so get the 12pt design font (cmbx12) if you use `\scalebox` you would get the 17pt display font cmbx17 scaled down.

Comment: Many thanks @David Carlisle for your comments.  As for the `\large` vs `Large` , I sometimes find myself trying to present a box or a minipage in a document , which for various reasons, must be pleasing to the eye. "Large" may be too large and "large" may be too small---so, I select one, and try to scale accordingly. Interpreting your comments, it sounds like given the choice, `scalebox`  may be the better alternative in such situations.

Comment: @mlchristians generally I'd avoid using scalebox on text, tables etc it results in inconsistent font and rule sizes. for "non standard" font sizes I'd use `\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont` rarther than `\LARGE\scalefont{.75}` it's just clearer what the result is, and doesn't require any package.

Comment: I have not done that before. I expect to try that out soon and hopefully get used to it---though old habits are hard to break. Thanks again.