# Adjusting the Vertical Spacing Between Consecutive Lines with a Scaled Typewriter Font

Tags: scaling, description, typewriter, vertical-spacing

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{scalefnt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{description}
\item {\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont{No one should be ashamed to admit they are wrong, which is but saying, in other words, that they are wiser today than they were yesterday. ---Alexander Pope}}

\item {\fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont{\scalefont{0.65}{No one should be ashamed to admit they are wrong, which is but saying, in other words, that they are wiser today than they were yesterday. ---Alexander Pope}}}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I adjust (downward, in this instance) the vertical space between consecutive lines in the scaled (second) quote?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to finish the paragraph before you switch back to another font size to get correct spacing.

Comment: hmmm add another "again" to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/634063/how-to-proportionately-adjust-vertical-spacing-between-the-lines-in-a-scaled-min#comment1580969_634063

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\scalebox`, for some reason, does not work with this example.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm not sure what you mean by "finish the paragraph".

Comment: @mlchristians Try with `Pope\par` and you should see the real line spacing of the fontsize

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ah! yes! Thank you. Perhaps you will post this as an answer; and if possible, an explanation as to why `\par` is needed. Thanks again.

Comment: scalebox unrelated, there as here you need to end the paragraph

Comment: @mlchristians There should be a lot of duplicates of this problem.

Comment: see the answer you accepted last time!! As always the line spacing used in a paragraph is the one in force at the end of the paragraph, so if you want the baseline spacing that is set by \scalefont you need (just as if you had used \small) to end the paragraph within its scope.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz O.k. thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I had looked at the answer; but I don't recall seeing `\par` someplace. Perhaps I should look again.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for the link; and for the previous comment.

Comment: in that case I explained the issue in the text, In that case it didn't need `\par`  I just deleted `{...}` so the paragraph ended in the scope of the size